# Why doesn't "set -v" seem to work in a subshell in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging

It looks like `set -v` doesn't work when in a subshell? Why?

(`set -x` does work in a subshell, but the output is a bit busier).

```
$ cat foo.sh
set -v
date
set +v > /dev/null 2>&1

$ bash foo.sh
date
Fri Mar  3 14:52:34 PST 2017
set +v > /dev/null 2>&1

$ cat foo_subshell.sh
(
  set -v
  date
)

$ bash foo_subshell.sh
Fri Mar  3 14:52:42 PST 2017
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says:

> `-v`      Print shell input lines **as they are read**.

When you write a subshell in parentheses, the entire subshell is read, then it's executed. So the `set -v` command isn't executed until *after* all the commands are read, so it's too late for it to print them.